# Kline Calculus intuitive approach Chapter 3 problem 12

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem is as follows : Water drops flow out from a small opening at the rate of one drop per second and fall vertically with an acceleration of 32 ft/sec^2. Determine the distance between two successive drops exactly 1 second after the second one has left the opening. I went to see the solution and I still don't understand how they arrive at the solution. The solution says that for drop one d=0,v=0 at t=0 so I assume that these parameters are taken when drop one is forming at the opening. Then they proceed to say that for the second drop v=32t+C. And so to find C they say that V=0, when t=1. Now this is where I am confused. 1 second later after it left the opening how can the second drop have a velocity of zero. The same procedure is applied to find C of the distance equation which is d= 16t^2-32t+C. They proceed to say that at t=1, s= 0. How can that be? The drop surely made some distance 1 second after it left the opening. The only explanation I could come up with is that they took the 1 second after the second drop left as initial conditions. But if so then they are not allowed to say d=0,v=0 when t=0 because that refers to when the first drop was at the opening.

Comment: At time $t=1$ the second drop is just starting to fall and so its distance (from the spout) is 0 and its velocity is 0.

Comment: I see. Yeah that makes a lot of sense now. Thank you so much